# Typing Arrow Pointing Leftwards Then Curving Upwards

Tags: unicode, microsoft-onenote, character-encoding, special-characters, microsoft-onenote-2013

It seems that the **Arrow Pointing Leftwards Then Curving Upwards** character doesn't exist. The [Arrow Pointing Rightwards Then Curving Upwards](http://unicode-table.com/en/2934/) already exists. I've searched for how to write that character, but unfortunately none helped. I've came up with this alternative [Leftwards Arrow with Tip Upwards](http://unicode-table.com/en/2B11/). But, actually, I need it curved. How could I type the *Arrow Pointing Leftwards Then Curving Upwards* in a text editor (e.g OneNote)?

Comment: If no such Unicode character exists how can you possibly type it? If you have a font with that glyph (you can create it in a font editor) then perhaps you can use that instead, or simply use an image.

Comment: It seems that there's no Unicode character for it. I'm asking for an alternative that works on any device. So, using a font won't work for me because on viewing my text on multiple devices, the font has to be installed first.